# How can I add to a list with two defined generics?

Tags: java, list

I'm having problems performing an add() on a list defined like this

```
private final List<TraitGroup <? extends TRAIT_Able>> traitGroups;
```

Ideally, I'd like to simply `traitGroups.add(TYPE);`

But try as I might, I just can't get the generics quite right.

As requested, the Trait_Able interface and TraitGroup Class are below...

### TRAIT_Able

```
public interface TRAIT_Able {
String getNAME();
String toString();
}
```

### TraitGroup

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class TraitGroup <T extends TRAIT_Able>{
private final List <AbstractTrait<T>> abstractTraits;

public TraitGroup() {
    abstractTraits = new LinkedList<AbstractTrait<T>>();
}

public AbstractTrait<T>[] toArray() {
    AbstractTrait<T>[] abstractTrait = new AbstractTrait[this.abstractTraits.size()];
    for (int i =0; i < abstractTrait.length; i ++)
        abstractTrait[i] = this.abstractTraits.get(i); 
    return abstractTrait;
}

public void add(AbstractTrait<T>... source) 
{
    boolean wasFound;
    for (AbstractTrait<T> abstractTrait : source) 
    {
        wasFound = false;
        for (AbstractTrait<T> trait : this.abstractTraits) 
        {
            if (abstractTrait.equals(trait))
            {
                wasFound = true;
                trait.add(abstractTrait);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!wasFound)
            this.abstractTraits.add(abstractTrait);
    }
}


public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(  "Trait group: " +
                " Size: " + this.abstractTraits.size() + "\n");


    return sb.toString();
}

}
```

Comment: Can you show your TraitGroup and Traitable classes?

Comment: Could you also show the declaration of `TYPE`? What's wrong with `List<TraitGroup<TRAIT_Able>>`?

Comment: TYPE has no declaration, I meant that as an example of what I'd like to do. I'm just not sure how to define TYPE so that I can add it to that list with that definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the unbounded wildcard is that it does not represent `any` type, it represents `unknown` type. Your declaration, in essence, reads in plain English as:

> A list of TraitGroups that accept some **unknown** type that extends
>   TRAIT_able.

And not

> A list of TraitGroups that accept **any** type that extends TRAIT_able.

An important distinction. And because the type is unknown, the compiler will reject any attempt to add to the list (because you've asked for compile time checks, but the compiler cannot assure that the type you are trying to add to the list is actually valid for it). In essence, you are trying to define a heterogenous collection of objects, and as such you might as well declare your list as such:

```
private final List<TraitGroup <TRAIT_Able>> traitGroups;
```

Comment: -1, sorry: this is wrong. `traitGroups` has type `List<TraitGroup<? extends TRAIT_Able>>`, which means that you can `add` any expression of type `TraitGroup<? extends TRAIT_Able>` -- such as (for example) any expression of type `TraitGroup<TRAIT_Able>`. (You're probably thinking of cases like `List<? extends TRAIT_Able>`, where you can't safely `add` anything because there's no way to know that a given reference is a subtype of whatever `? extends TRAIT_Able` is standing in for. But that problem doesn't occur here.)